# django one click deploy to dreamhost

Tags: python, django, mercurial, dreamhost

I have a python/django application that im running on my dreamhost account.  Excuse me for the novice question, but I'm a Java programmer by day and relatively new to python.

Ideally what I'd like to do is set something up where I can take the code I have locally, upload it to my server and then touch the restart.txt file.  I realize I could probably accomplish this with a bat/ftp script, but I has hoping for something a bit more advanced/robust.  I have a local mercurial repository where I'm doing version control, is it at all feasible to get mercurial running on dreamhost, and then set up so that when I push changes from my local repo to the server repo, those get deployed to the proper location?

Are there other solutions I should be looking at?  I guess all I'm looking for is someone to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

All the cool guys are using [fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/) nowadays. It's exactly what you looking for.

Comment: sounds like exactly what I'm looking for.  I'll give it a shot.  thanks.